# catch change in security permission of file without blocking

Tags: python-2.7, file, security, pywin32, file-security

I want to catch change in security permission of file without blocking till the change is made, like an event that popup when the change is made.

I also don't want to install any third party modules or softwares.

The main requirement of this is to be in some of `win32` modules or built-in modules.

I'm currently watching for security change by this function:

```
    import win32con, win32file
    def security_watcher():

        specific_file = "specific.ini"
        path_to_watch = "." 
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001
        hDir = win32file.CreateFile(path_to_watch,
                                    FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
                                    win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | 
                                    win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | 
                                    win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                                    None,
                                    win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
                                    win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
                                    None)
        results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDir,
                                                  1024,
                                                  False,
                                                  win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
                                                  None,
                                                  None)
        print results
        for action, file_name in results:
            if file_name == specific_file:
               # wake another function to do something about that
```

**Note:** I need it non blocking because I use this function in GUI Application and it freezes the GUI.

Comment: What OS? Clearly Windows, but what version? How many files do you need to watch? (If it's just one, you could always launch a separate blocking process that writes to a pipe or such.)

Comment: Windows 7 and only one file. 
How do I do that?

Comment: And if I write to pipe it anyway blocks, because if the GUI process wait for reading from the pipe I came into blocking issue if nothing changed yet.

Comment: Non-blocking reads on a pipe are easy to do (don't know the Windows syntax otomh, unfortunately). So is checking a log file to see if it has grown since you last checked.

Comment: But of course the ideal solution would be a non-blocking version of the call you have, as you propose.

Comment: The problem is if I do that I'll need thread that watching for any data on the pipe. when I get that data I need to modify some label in the GUI Application, which will make some unusual errors since the element isn't modified by the mainloop of the GUI.
EDIT: I'll try it anyway and see if I can make it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind (or can't avoid) adding some threading overhead, you can launch a separate process or thread that waits on the blocking call to `win32.ReadDirectoryChangesW()` that you already have. When it receives a change, it writes the result to a pipe shared with the main thread of your GUI.

Your GUI can periodically execute a non-blocking read at the appropriate point in your code (presumably, where you now call `win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW()`). Do make sure to wait a bit between reads, or your app will spend 100% of its time on non-blocking reads.

You can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896288/699305) how to set up a non-blocking read on a pipe in an OS-independent way. The final bit will look like this:

```
try:  
    results = q.get_nowait()
except Empty:
    pass
else:  
    for line in results.splitlines():
        # Parse and use your result format
        ...
        if file_name == specific_file:
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I use that and I find a hacky way to use the thread also!